# what is the full formulation of this expression?

Tags: summation, notation, systems-of-equations

I have this expression that i am confused about:
$ \sum_{\forall i \in I(a)} D_{j,i}.x_i \geq  1 $ ,  $ \forall C_j \in J(a) $

Does it equal to the following one:
$ \sum_{i \in I(a)} D_{1,i}.x_i \geq  1 $ , $ \sum_{\forall i \in I(a)} D_{2,i}.x_i \geq  1 $, ..., $ \sum_{\forall i \in I(a)} D_{n,i}.x_i \geq  1 $, $ $ if $max(j)$ =$n$ ?

Otherwise how to comprehend the `j` index in the expression, and it affects the expression

Comment: Where did this arise?  Both $\sum_\forall$ and $\ge =$ are nonstandard.

Comment: you're right, i corrected that